# Java convert double to date format

Tags: java, date, type-conversion, double, long-integer

I have made a little app in ios+firebase, now I am trying to connect android. In ios I save date as double (for example: -242528463.775282), but then I trying to retrieve same double in java it giving me another date.

in IOS - 01.07.2009
in Java - 29.12.1969

```
  double myDouble = date;
  long myLong = (long) (myDouble);
  System.out.println(myLong);

  Date itemDate = new Date(itemLong);
  String myDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(itemDate);             
  editTextDate.setText(myDateStr);
```

Is it possible to convert double to date without converting to long?

Comment: Are you storing dates as timestamps?

Comment: What does the double represent?  Days since 1-1-1970?  Something else?

Comment: double represent timeIntervalSinceNow

Comment: By the way, this is a terrible way to store date-time values. One reason is that your use of floating-point technology may **alter your data**. Floating-point trades away accuracy for speed of execution. In doing so extraneous digits may be added to your decimal fraction. I suggest strings in [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats instead, or date-time data types if your database offers them.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `double` represents the number of seconds of you date from now, and the `Date` constructor in Java is expecting a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, you have to multiply your number to get a number of milliseconds (`* 1000`) and substract that from the current number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 (`System.currentTimeMillis()`):

```
double myDouble = -242528463.775282;
long myLong = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long) (myDouble * 1000));
System.out.println(myLong);

Date itemDate = new Date(myLong);
String myDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(itemDate);
System.out.println(myDateStr);
```

But, the problem with the way you store your dates is that if you are calling this code today and tomorrow it will not return the same date, as the current time is changing. You should use `timeIntervalSince1970` instead of `timeIntervalSinceNow`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a play around with statements below. In particular;
  long myLong = todate.getTime();
and store this to interpret later perhaps?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class dateConvertDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date todate = new Date();
        System.out.println(todate);

        long myLong = todate.getTime();
        System.out.println(myLong);

        double myDouble = (double)myLong;
        System.out.println(myDouble);

        String myDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(myLong);             
        System.out.println(myDateStr);

    }
}
```